# Are Index Sets always well ordered?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory, well-orders

Are indexing sets always well-ordered? Since if we have an operation on a collection indexed by $\Gamma$, such as a sum $\sum_{\gamma\in\Gamma}a_\gamma$ or Tychonoff product $\prod\{X_\gamma:\gamma\in\Gamma\}$, where the order of the operands is thought of as important, is an implicit ordering assumed?

My guess is that $\sum_{\gamma\in\Gamma}a_\gamma$ is not a well-defined object for infinite $\Gamma$, since even if a well-ordered indexing set is assumed, the value in the case of a conditionally convergent sequence is unclear, and for the product $\prod\{X_\gamma:\gamma\in\Gamma\}$, I suppose order is not important per se, since we can access the "$\gamma$th coordinate" using projections $\pi_\gamma\colon\prod\{X_\gamma:\gamma\in\Gamma\}\to X_\gamma$.

But is there no sense of "the first entry" with infinite products, only the "$\gamma$th" one? (Assuming the indexes are not themselves ordinals.)

Comment: What do you mean by $\sum_{\gamma \in \Gamma} a_\gamma$? Is this a sum of ordinals? Is it your notation for disjoint union (i.e. $\coprod_{\gamma \in \Gamma} a_\gamma$)? Something else?

Comment: Apologies, I did not make it clear. I meant by it a usual sum of real numbers. For finite $\Gamma$ it is clearly well-defined, for countable $\Gamma$ it is well-defined if the sum converges absolutely. Perhaps not the best example; I think the product illustrates my question better.

Comment: The product is really something different, and works for arbitrary sets. The point is that you are not talking about multiplication of reals here but about products of sets, which is something very different. That means that everything you said makes sense for these products (you can indeed define such a product for a $\Gamma$ without any kind of order on $\Gamma$, and then there is no "first entry", as you already argued).

Comment: @MarkKamsma But I ask this question in view of the fact that $X\times Y\times Z$, for example, clearly has a first entry, as does $X^\omega=X\times X \times \cdots$. So I am right in suggesting that there is a "first" entry only if a well-order on $\Gamma$ is imposed?

Comment: In case $\Gamma$ is a well-order you definitely have a first entry. There are weaker conditions, for example when $\Gamma$ is a tree (e.g. take $\Gamma$ to be the powerset of $\mathbb{N}$, ordered by inclusion). Then there is still a first entry (corresponding to the root), but you can no longer really find a second entry.

Comment: For the sum things are different. When talking about sums of real numbers we usually only care about a countable sum at most, indexed by the natural numbers (and thus by a well-ordered set). If you want different kinds of sums, you need to define what those mean first. This is not directly clear, not even for all well-orders. What if $\Gamma = \omega + \omega$, for example? For uncountable well-orders you will definitely get into some trouble.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I asked this because when studying Tychonoff products, I always visualised in my mind's eye some "infinite tuples", but that is inaccurate, because of the fact that, as you confirm, there is no "first entry".

Comment: I would say that a set of "infinite tuples" is still not a bad way to visualize Tychonoff products. An element of $X^n$ is simply a function $f : \{1,2,...,n\} \to X$. You don't actually need the ordering on the set $\{1,2,...,n\}$ to define the notion of a function whose domain is that set.

Answer (score 2):

Some remarks: the Cartesian product $\prod_{\gamma \in \Gamma} X_\gamma$ needs no order on the index set; it's just the set of functions $f: \Gamma \to \bigcup_{\gamma \in \Gamma} X_\gamma$ such that $f(\gamma) \in X_\gamma$ for every $\gamma$. It's not a "sequence". The $\gamma$'th coordinate is just the value of the function at $\gamma$. Projections are point evaluations.

$\sum_{\gamma \in \Gamma}a_\gamma$ is possible to define for any set $A$ in which all $a_\gamma$ lie and on which we have a commutative group operation $+$ and also a topology: let $G$ be the set of all *finite* subsets of $\Gamma$ with partial order $\subseteq$; this is a standard directed poset. Define a net $s: G \to A$ by $s(G)= \sum_{\gamma \in G} a_\gamma$ (which is a well-defined finite sum, for an Abelian group) and the limit in $A$ of this net, if it exists, (see a good book on general topology) is denoted $\sum_{\gamma \in \Gamma} a_\gamma$.
So also no order is needed. Theorem, if $A= \mathbb{R}$, standard $+$ and topology, $\sum_{\gamma \in \Gamma}a_\gamma$ exists iff $\{\gamma \in \Gamma: a_\gamma \neq 0\}$ is at most countable and the countable sum for this converges absolutely in any order we enumerate it. So it's quite a strong notion of infinite sum, in that light.